# Where in the MembershipProvider is set the connection string from the provider config?

Tags: asp.net, membership-provider

I was wondering where in the MembershipProvider is set the connection string from the provider config ?

Example, i create my custom provider called CustomMembershipProvider.. in the web.config there is a setting for the connection string.. but where it is set in the provider ? how to retrieve it from the config ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your provider config should reference a connection string in the connectionstrings section. The base provider doesn't store the connectionstring, as it's specific to a particular provider (eg an XML provider won't have a connection string).

The default SQL providers show the connectionstring either. If you're creating a custom provider & want to know what connectionstring you're using you'll need to create a public property for the value then reference `Membership.Provider` & cast it to your custom provider type to access the property.